# Updating Graphs and data with click actions in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I have an app with 3 actions,

1. load data by clicking button go(top left) - graphs should be output now
2. remove words by imputing a word in the remove bod and clicking "do" - graphs should be updated
3. replace a word, buy putting the word you want to replace in "find", and the replacement in "replace" and clicking act

The problem i am facing is that graphs are only being displayed if i click "go" and then "act", graphs are only displayed once i reach "act"

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(sp)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library("stringi")
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) #Data manipulation (also included in the tidyverse package)


ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow( 
    column( 4, titlePanel("Twitter Analytics")),
    column( 3),
    column( 4, 
            textInput("searchstring", 
                      label = "",
                      value = "")),
    column(1, 
           br(),
           actionButton("action", "go"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column( 12, tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("one",
               fluidRow(
                 column(3, textInput("removeString", label = "remove", value = ""), actionButton("remove", "do"),
                        textInput("find", label = "find", value = ""),textInput("rep", label = "replace", value = ""),actionButton("replace", "act"), 
                        checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", "select plots",
                                           choices <- c("Histogram", "Wordcloud", "network")),
                        sliderInput("topTerms",
                                    label = "top (n) terms", 
                                    min = 0, max = 25, value = 0)  ),
                 column(9,fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("ttext") )),

                          fluidRow(column(12,wordcloud2Output("wc2"))))
               )
      ),    
      tabPanel("two"),
      tabPanel("three")
    )
    )
  )
)




server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(go = 0, do = 0, act = 0 )


  observeEvent(input$action, {
    values$go <- 1
    values$do <- 0
    values$act <- 0

  })

  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    values$go <- 0
    values$do <- 1
    values$act <- 0
  })

  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    values$go <- 0
    values$do <- 0
    values$act <- 1
  })

  #tweet <- eventReactive(input$action,{
  cs<- reactiveVal(0)

  tweet <-reactive({

    if(values$go){

    num <- c(1,2,3,4,50)
    text <- c("this is love love something", "this is not hate hate hate something", "@something islove  rethched this not", " Shiny is love confusing me", "this is hate also somthing difficult")
    letter<- c("a", "b", "c", "D", "e")
    tweetdf <- data.frame(num, text, letter)
    tweetdf$text <- tolower(tweetdf$text)
    # tweetdf @UserName
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
    #remove punctuation
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tweetdf$text)
    #remove links
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("http\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove tabs
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("[ |\t]{2,}", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove blank spaces at the beginning
    tweetdf$text <- gsub("^ ", "", tweetdf$text)
    # Remove blank spaces at the end
    corpus <- iconv(tweetdf$text, to = "ASCII")
    corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
    corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
    cleanset <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
    cs(cleanset)}

     if(values$do){

      cleanset <- cs()
      cleanset <- tm_map(cleanset, removeWords, input$removeString)
      cs(cleanset)
     }

    if(values$act){

      cleanset <- cs()
      cleanset <- tm_map(cleanset, gsub, 
                         pattern = input$find, 
                         replacement = input$rep)
    cs(cleanset)

    }

    else
      {return()}
  })



    output$ttext <- renderPlot({ 
      if(is.null(tweet())){return()}
      else{
      cleanset <-cs()
      tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
      tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
      w <- rowSums(tdm)
        library(RColorBrewer)
        barplot(w)}

    })


    output$wc2 <- renderWordcloud2({
      if(is.null(tweet())){return()}
      else{
      library(wordcloud2)
      cleanset <-cs()
      tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
      tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
      w <- rowSums(tdm)
      w <- data.frame(names(w), w)
      colnames(w) <- c('word', 'freq')
      wordcloud2(w,
                 color = 'random-dark',
                 size = 0.7,
                 shape = 'circle',
                 rotateRatio = 0.5,
                 minSize = 1)}
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

can anyone please tell me what is going wrong i have only started using shiny a few days ago?

Comment: I see, I'm sorry. Could you explained a bit more each part of your application or give a simpler case, if possible ? For instance how useful is the searching bar for helping you ?

Comment: HI Remi, this is as simplified as i can make it do demo the purpose. the actual app is much more complex.

Basically the in the server.R i am loading the DF when button go is pressed, then a graph should be displayed or the word counts,  then the user should be able to say they wish to delete selected words and click do, to delete the selected word for the corpus
then the graphs should be updated to show this word has been deleted

Comment: Thanks ! It is clearer. Why not using only tm_map functions to clean your text ?

Comment: i did it that way as i was experimenting wit different ways to clean my data

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you are using several if. R doesn't know what things to return. So you could use this server, you don't need to replace 0 by `FALSE`.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(go = 0, do = 0, act = 0 )

  observeEvent(input$action, {
    values$go <- T
    values$do <- F
    values$act <- F
  })

  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    values$go <- F
    values$do <- T
    values$act <- F
  })

  observeEvent(input$replace, {
    values$go <- F
    values$do <- F
    values$act <- T
  })

  #tweet <- eventReactive(input$action,{
  cs <- reactiveVal(0)

  tweet <- reactive({
    cleanset <- cs()
    if(values$go){
      num <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 50)
      text <- c("this is love love something", "this is not hate hate hate something",
                "@something islove  rethched this not", " Shiny is love confusing me", "this is hate also somthing difficult")
      letter<- c("a", "b", "c", "D", "e")
      tweetdf <- data.frame(num, text, letter)
      tweetdf$text <- tolower(tweetdf$text)
      # tweetdf @UserName
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove punctuation
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove links
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("http\\w+", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove tabs
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("[ |\t]{2,}", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove blank spaces at the beginning
      tweetdf$text <- gsub("^ ", "", tweetdf$text)
      # Remove blank spaces at the end
      corpus <- iconv(tweetdf$text, to = "ASCII")
      corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
      corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
      cleanset <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
      return(cs(cleanset))}

    else if(values$do){
      cleanset <- tm_map(cleanset, removeWords, input$removeString)
      return(cs(cleanset))
    }

    else if(values$act){
      cleanset <- tm_map(cleanset, gsub, 
                         pattern = "input$find", 
                         replacement = "input$rep")
      return(cs(cleanset))
    }
    else
    {return()}
  })


  output$ttext <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(tweet())){
      return()}
    else{
      cleanset <- cs()
      tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
      tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
      w <- rowSums(tdm)
      barplot(w)}

  })


  output$wc2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    if(is.null(tweet())){return()}
    else{
      cleanset <-cs()
      tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
      tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
      w <- rowSums(tdm)
      w <- data.frame(names(w), w)
      colnames(w) <- c('word', 'freq')
      wordcloud2(w,
                 color = 'random-dark',
                 size = 0.7,
                 shape = 'circle',
                 rotateRatio = 0.5,
                 minSize = 1)}
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi Remi, many thanks, the go button is working as expected, however the act button is still not working as intended, do you have any ideas

Comment: the other issue is that as soon as the button is clicked this element remains reactive, is there a way to switch this off

Comment: Actionbutton in R shiny increment of one so if you want to do that you may use a checkboxinput control.

Comment: Is answering your question ? If yes, you could validate it. Thanks.